# Better way to connect from belongsTo to has many relation in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5

so I have a code that shows all my product

```
                              @foreach($products as $product)
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 event-item-col ">
                                <div class="card card-event info-overlay">
                                    <div class="img has-background h-50">
                                        <div class="pop-info ">
                                            <span class="event-badges ">
                                                <span class="badge price-tag big badge-default">{{$product->price}}</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="/product/{{$product->id}}" class="event-pop-link">
                                            <span class="event-badges ">
                                            <span class="badge badge-danger"> if he buy</span>
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="event-pop-info">
                                                <p class="badge">{{$product->price}}</p>
                                                <p class="publisher">by <strong><?php $id = $product->user_id; $users = $user->findOrFail($id); echo $users->first; ?> <?php echo $user->last ?></strong></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="event-details.html">
                                            <img alt="340x230" class="card-img-top img-responsive h-100" data-holder-rendered="true" src="image/products/product{{$product->id}}.jpg"> </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body h-50">
                                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                                <a href="/product/{{$product->id}}">{{$product->pname}}</a>
                                            </h4>
                                            <p class="card-tex" style="overflow: hidden">{{$product->smalldescription}}</p>
                                            <div class="card-event-info">
                                                <p class="event-location"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i>
                                                    <a class="location" href="/user/product/{{$id}}"><?php echo $users->first; ?> <?php echo $user->last ?></a></p>
                                                <p class="event-time"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"> {{$product->created_at->format('m/d/Y')}}</i></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           @endforeach
```

and this is my controller

```
    public function index()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $products = product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->Paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null);
    return view('welcome', compact('products', 'user'));

}
```

like you can see in my view I have this code

```
<?php $id = $product->user_id; $users = $user->findOrFail($id); echo $users->first; ?> <?php echo $user->last ?>
```

that makes me able to get the name of the user that create this product, product and user table has one too many relations.i want to change this code to a better and smaller code.

```
product->user->first
```

don't work.
I tried it so many ways but that just doesn't work.
if anyone can help me to get data with laravel way I will be grateful. (sry if my question is duplicate, I tried so many ways but didn't work )
 to give u guys more info this is my class

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
use Friendable;

protected $fillable = [
    'first','last', 'email', 'password','phone','question','answer','description',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function products()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);

}

}
```

and product class :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

the class product extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'part_id', 'smalldescription', 'description', 'pname', 'link', 'price',
];

public function users()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would like to point you out that you have already defined the relation in your product model you could use that to access the related user by calling the function. I would also like to suggest you to change the function name in your product model from users to user as belongsTo returns only single instance of the related model.

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Coming back to your query when querying products use with load a relation like in your case it would be.

```
product::with('user')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->Paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null);
```

Then inside your foreach loop on blade get user's name calling user function on $product like:

```
$product->user->name
```

I would also suggest to go through the laravel documentation about eloquent relations again.
[Querying a relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: thx @HarisShah it work perfectly, and i learnd a lot ty again.

Comment: @AhmadVahedi Glad I could help